# Connection String for Database First does not work when retrieving data

Tags: oracle, model, web-config, connection-string

I have the following connection string to generate my Database First Model `connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AirInvoicing.csdl|res://*/Models.AirInvoicing.ssdl|res://*/Models.AirInvoicing.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client; provider connection string=&quot;TNS_ADMIN=C:\Repos\air-invoicing\air-invoicing;USER ID=user;PASSWORD=password;DATA SOURCE=BETA&quot;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"` however when I use the same connection string to retrieve data I receive this error `'metadata' is an invalid connection string attribute`. If I remove the metadata I receive errors from the `UnintentionalCodeFirstException()` This is the code I am using to retrieve data `IQueryable<AIR_IMPORT_STATUS_TYPE> test = context.AIR_IMPORT_STATUS_TYPE .Where(x => x.STATUS_NAME == Name);` Do I need two connection strings?